# Vim, word frequency function and French accents

Tags: vim, diacritics, word-frequency

I have recently discovered the Vim Tip n° 1531 (Word frequency statistics for a file).

As suggested I put the following code in my .vimrc

```
function! WordFrequency() range
  let all = split(join(getline(a:firstline, a:lastline)), '\A\+')
  let frequencies = {}
  for word in all
    let frequencies[word] = get(frequencies, word, 0) + 1
  endfor
  new
  setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=hide noswapfile tabstop=20
  for [key,value] in items(frequencies)
    call append('$', key."\t".value)
  endfor
  sort i
endfunction
command! -range=% WordFrequency <line1>,<line2>call WordFrequency()
```

It works fine except for accents and other french specifics (latin small ligature a or o, etc…).

What am I supposed to add in this function to make it suit my needs ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 8-bit characters you can try to change the split pattern from `\A\+` to
`[^[:alpha:]]\+`.

Comment: thanks, this solution answers my Q1 and Q2, with the exception, noted by romaini of "aujourd'hui", of course. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The pattern `\A\+` matches any number of consecutive non-alphabetic characters which — unfortunately — includes multibytes characters like our beloved `çàéô` and friends.

That means that your text is split at spaces AND at multibyte characters.

With `\A\+`, the phrase

```
Rendez-vous après l'apéritif.
```

gives:

```
ap      1
apr     1
l       1
Rendez  1
ritif   1
s       1
vous    1
```

If you are sure your text doesn't include fancy spaces you could replace this pattern with `\s\+` that matches whitespace only but it's probably to liberal.

With this pattern, `\s\+`, the same phrase gives:

```
après       1
l'apéritif. 1
Rendez-vous 1
```

which, I think, is closer to what you want.

Some customizing may be necessary to exclude punctuations.

Comment: First of all, thanks : it works. But just for the sake of it, how do I exlude apostrophes (and get, in your example apéritif)

Comment: First of all, thanks : it works. But just for the sake of it : 1) how should I exclude punctuations (in fact commas and dots) ; 2) how should I exlude apostrophes (and get, in your example apéritif alone) ; and 3) how should I proceed to have "éminent" listed before "emmener" and not at the end of the word list as all the other accented first characters of words ? Sorry for being a nuisance (but why just be annoying when you can be obnoxious ? ;-))

Comment: **Q1:** Maybe by cleaning up your selection with a regular expression before you do the split and removing all single letters or meaningless pairs like `qu` in a second pass. **Q2:** By adding it to the pattern used for splitting but you'll have to be careful not to split words like `aujourd'hui`. **Q3:** See `:help sort` for what options are available. I think you'll have to resort to some external library/script, Vim's `:sort` command doesn't seem to have much options. Seem `$ man sort` for a possible solution.

Comment: @romaini : ib. made a suggestion which seems to answer Q1 and Q2, excepted, as you noted, for aujourd'hui. As for sorting, I shall delve into $man sort. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
function! WordFrequency() range
  " Whitespace and all punctuation characters except dash and single quote
  let wordSeparators = '[[:blank:],.;:!?%#*+^@&/~_|=<>\[\](){}]\+'
  let all = split(join(getline(a:firstline, a:lastline)), wordSeparators)
  "...
endfunction
```

If [all punctuation characters](http://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/regex/character-classes/) should be word separators, the expression shortens to

```
let wordSeparators = '[[:blank:][:punct:]]\+'
```