# Is there a function in vim to get the list of words in a buffer?

Tags: vim

Is there a function in Vim to get the list of words inside a buffer?
Or should I resort to writing a vimscript for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is to obtain a list of words, a question I asked to SO (with specific addendum : french accents) and the answers I got (from ib. and romainl) may be what you need :

[Vim, word frequency function and French accents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525839/vim-word-frequency-function-and-french-accents)

Of course it goes :

```
:%call WordFrequency()
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

There is no builtin function for that available. But you can script yourself something using VimL:

```
:echo uniq(sort(split(join(getline(1,'$'), "\n"))))
```

But that needs at  least Vim 7.4.218 for the uniq function.

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/\w\+//gn
```

reports 374 words but LibreOffice only reports 344.

Defining what a "word" is should be a good start, don't you think?